# Dropdown of Static Blocks on Catalog Product in Admin

Tags: magento

I posted this same question on magento but the community here tends to be a bit more active and I'd like to try and get an answer sooner rather than later LOL>

Static Blocks I see are extremely nice and use full however I find myself in a situation where I wan to add a custom attribute to the products page in the admin. This custom attribute I want to be a dropdown menu of the current static blocks.

My main concern is upgrade friendly and how to achieve this. I was hoping I could do it with the attributes manager but it looks like I'll have to do it programmatically.

Comment: If you are ok with programming - this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233133/magento-how-do-you-return-results-of-unlimited-cms-static-blocks-with-certain or do you require  final solution ?

Comment: Well what I'm wanting to know is where are the file located that I can updated and not worry about being over written with future updates from magento... also this customization will appear in the admin area