# How to write a php loop in Magento footer?

Tags: php, css, magento, loops, magento-1.7

Hi to all Developers out there!!!

I am using the below commands in **footer.phtml** in order to fetch all my **cms/blocks**
 in the magento's **footer**

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home')->toHtml();?>


<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact')->toHtml();?>


<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('blog')->toHtml();?>
```

I wonder if I could find somekind of a loop in order to fetch **all my blocks** ( home, contact , blog etc,etc) in order to avoid repeating the above code...

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What if you want to use a block that DOESN'T want to be in your footer?

Comment: @Karl true :) but There is no plan for further blocks.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're after is pure code reuse, something like this will work

```
<?php $_blocks = array('home','contact','block'); ?>
<?php foreach($_blocks as $_blockName): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_blockName)->toHtml();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Just add new block names to the `$_blocks` array.

You could also do this for **all** your blocks with something like this

```
    <?php $_blocks = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection(); ?>
    <?php foreach($_blocks as $_block): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_block->getIdentifier())->toHtml();?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

but as other have mentioned, that seems like a bad idea w/r/t new blocks added to the system.

Answer (score 1):

This post may help:
[Magento - How do you return results of unlimited CMS Static blocks (with certain "Identifier") to a CMS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233133/magento-how-do-you-return-results-of-unlimited-cms-static-blocks-with-certain)

You can use collections in order to get all the cms blocks and you can also filter them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Or you must write your own function for it.